# Is it possible to use Url.Action just returning the controller name and action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get `Url.Action()` to return just the controller and action name.

I have a dictionary like so:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { "SiteUrl", config.Url },
                    { "ResetPasswordLink", Url.Action("ResetPassword", new { token = e.Token }) }
                };
```

- `config.Url` returns `www.mysite.com/foo/`
- `Url.Action("ResetPassword", new { token = e.Token })` returns
  `/foo/account/resertpassword???token=blaBlaBla`
- The two are concatenated, returning `www.mysite.com/foo/foo/......`

This link obviously doesn't work. I can't remove "foo" from `config.Url` else other things break. I feel like this is something stupid and simple I am missing.

I could easily trim the /foo, but that doesn't seem quite right, or maybe I am over thinking it?

I've tried a bunch of different `Url.Action()` overloads and route values, but can't quite get what I need.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, which is why I'm not adding it as an answer, but if what you need is the full path to an action, including domain, the `Url.Action(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, string protocol);` overload should return the full path to the action, with any additional routeValues like `token`, including the domain, so you won't need the dictionary. I don't know if there are other reasons for you to use the dictionary, but this would provide the end result you're looking for, I believe.

Comment: thanks. The dictionary is used for generating emails. It contains values that are replaced in a template. In the case the dictionary can still but used, I just tweak the email template to accept one value instead of two. So yeah this works for me, thanks.